# Political Party Accounts XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I've recently joined a political party and I'm pressuring them to be financially accountable.
They are new so this is far more likely to actually happen, then I plan on using their accountability to force other parties to do the same. See I'm crafty like that.

My issue is that in order to make this sort of data really easily accessible for people who want to aggregate it I need some sort of standard XML schema.
I could sit down with an accountant and thrash one out but I'd much prefer if there was some sort of open standard xml schema already.

So if you know of something like this, or even something similar please post it as an answer.

If you are interested the country is Ireland and the party is http://www.irishdemocrats.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the motivation is irrelevant, you might find the removal of your first paragraph a good idea.

Comment: Actually it's not for personal finance, nor is it profit focused but rather all about transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you design your own, take a look at [XBRL](http://www.xbrl.org/Home/) and in particular the Irish / European taxonomy.

It's quite complex to get started, but once you figure out which particular information you need to report it should be straight-forward. I suggest you look at examples instead of the full standard, or you will go insane...

Comment: Have you or anyone else used XBRL? I've come across it